# Set and get Image in objectbox

Tags: database, dart, mobile-application, objectbox

I want to set and get image from local storage, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with the help of http and base64String

```
Future<String> getNetworkImage()async{
    final data = await _firestore.collection("chiggos.vikash@gmail.com").doc("GymDetails").get();
    final imageurl = data.get("url");
    final uri = Uri.parse(imageurl);
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    final unit8listimage = response.bodyBytes;
    final base64image = base64Encode(unit8listimage);
    final object = SetImage(imageurl: base64image);

    if(!_objectBox.setimage.isEmpty()){
      _objectBox.setimage.remove;
    }
    
    _objectBox.setimage.put(object);

    final getimage = _objectBox.setimage.get(object.id);
    return getimage!.imageurl;  
}
```

Comment: You should be able to avoid base64 overhead by storing response.bodyBytes into a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your want image format is, but most likely you can use **base64**.

Probably [this page](https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-base64-image/) will be helpful.